Is this water damage in my attic?
New build townhouse, took a peek in the attic and noticed this weird streaking on the common wall. Almost looks like water damage but it’s uniform going horizontally and vertically along the joints. Any ideas on what this could be?


There are stains, but I do not see any damage, per se.

Those don't appear to be joints. All actual joints are taped as is required for a firewall in multi-unit dwellings. What are those straight lines inside the water stains?

To echo RMDman, it does look like there was water at some point, but the pattern is very strange, following the dark lines as it does. That's not necessarily "damage".

Trying to figure out what those stains are from. Did they just install stained drywall? Is there an active leak? They way the brown lines present them selves both vertically and horizontally is weird.

Well, we're about the last people you should ask. Someone has to look around and test for moisture. Find out what structure corresponds to those lines.

What caused the lines?  A guess is maybe the panels got wet on the edges before ever being installed.   My strong gut feeling is that it is nothing to worry about.

Where are you located? You need to know what is on the other side of the common wall. Is it conditioned space? Do the ducts drop from the ceiling or blow up from the floor?

No ducts in that wall. They blow from the floor, hvac in the basement. Other side of the wall is identical these are row towns.

I'd say it had a leak and might still. I think water was/is coming in up top and running along framing. Given it is a new build, I wouldn't expect "damage" quite yet.

Zoom waaaaay in and follow the stain upwards.  Where that stain would meet the roof, you can just barely see what looks like a seam between two panels of roof sheathing.  It's possible that you have/had some damage to your shingles and water got behind them, ran through a gap between the edges of those panels, and then down the wall.  The horizontal stain is definitely unusual.  Perhaps the water got to the joint in the wall panels and traveled along the edges of the board to the right and then down?  The stain gets taller as you move left to right, which suggests water moving in that direction.
It's certainly hard to tell for sure from just a photo.  If it's still an active leak, you should be able to feel moisture where the stain meets the roof the next time you get a heavy rain.  Probing it with a moisture meter would be even better.  It appears to be underneath the white tape on the joint, though, and there's no visible staining on the roof decking. I suspect this was something that happened during construction (perhaps before the building was watertight) and that isn't an active problem.  I'd still recommend taking a closer look at it, though. Leaks can turn nasty very quickly.
